# Vue3 How to parse SFC string to a component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-sfc

I want to compile sfc string as a component like this:

```js
<script setup>
import { parseToComponent } from './';

const sfcString = `
    <script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    const count = ref(0);
    </script>

    <template>
        <div class="label">{{ count }}</div>
        <button @click="count++">increase</button>
    </template>

    <style scoped>
    .label {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
`;

const parsedComponent = parseToComponent(sfcString);
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <parsedComponent />
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

How can I do this?

I tried to use `vue/compiler-sfc` to parse and compile `sfcString`, but I don't know how to convert it to component:

```js
import { parse, compileTemplate, compileScript, compileStyle } from 'vue/compiler-sfc';

export function parseToComponent(sfcString) {
    const { descriptor } = parse(sfcString);

    const scriptOptions = ...;
    const templateOptions = ...;
    const styleOptions = ...;

    // succeed, but how to use them to take a component?
    const script = compileScript(descriptor, scriptOptions);
    const template = compileTemplate(templateOptions);
    const style = compileStyle(styleOptions);
}
```

Comment: why would you need to do this? just create a `.vue` file with that content - have you read the docs?  https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/main/packages/compiler-sfc

Comment: @JaromandaX For some reason that content is not a static file, I can just get it from a string.

Comment: @JarmandaX Yes, I try to concatenate compiled code and use `eval()`  or `new Blob()` to run and import it, but it seems not work.

Comment: `For some reason that content is not a static file` because you made it a static string ... why? anyway `vue/compiler-sfc` is not a runtime module, it's a build time module, so it's not going to work - [Vue SFC is a framework-specific file format and **must be pre-compiled**](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html#how-it-works) - your code is trying to compile it at run-time ... the pre in pre-compiled means it isn't done at run-time

Comment: having said that - [vue3-sfc-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader) may be just what you need

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, I know about that. But how [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/) or other online editor work? I browsed the code and it used `iframe`, is it mean `iframe` can `pre-compied` the sfc code?

Comment: `vue3-sfc-loader` seems can do this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [vue3-sfc-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader) to implemented it:

```js
import * as Vue from 'vue';
import { loadModule } from 'vue3-sfc-loader';

export function parseToComponent(sfcString) {
    const id = genRandomId(id);
    const options = {
        moduleCache: { vue: Vue },
        async getFile(url) {
            return Promise.resolve(sfcString);
        },
        addStyle(styleString) {
            let style = document.getElementById(id);
            if (!style) {
                style = document.createElement('style');
                style.setAttribute('id', id);
                const ref = document.head.getElementsByTagName('style')[0] || null;
                document.head.insertBefore(style, ref);
            }
            style.textContent = styleString;
        }
    };
    const component = loadModule(`${id}.vue`, options);
    return Vue.defineAsyncComponent(() => component);
}
```

Use in code(need `markRaw()`):

```html
<script setup>
import { markRaw } from 'vue';
import { parseToComponent } from './';

const sfcString = `...`;
const parsedComponent = markRaw(parseToComponent(sfcString));
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <parsedComponent />
    </div>
</template>
```